# Trying to multiply within the public static void. Any help is appreciated

Tags: java

So, for one of my homework pieces I have to make a Body Mass Index. When I asked my teacher about how to do math within the public void main, he explained that I could just do it in the void main. But when I try It gives me "The Operator * is undefined for the arguments type(s): String, Int".

Here's the code and Instructions:

(Instructions)
Create a new Java project named Your_Name_BMI. Create a class named BMI and write a program using JOptionPane dialog boxes that calculates and displays a person’s body mass index (BMI). The BMI is often used to determine whether a person with a sedentary lifestyle is overweight or under-weight for his or her height. A person’s BMI is calculated with the following formula:BMI = (weight*703) /(height2) Where weight is measured in pounds and height is measured in inches.  The program should display messages to the user asking for their weight and height and store the values in appropriately named variables. After making the calculations the program should display a message indicating whether the person has optimal weight, is underweight, or is overweight. A sedentary person’s weight is considered optimal if his or her BMI is between 18.5 and 25. If the BMI is less than 18.5, the person is considered underweight. If the BMI value is greater than 25, the person is considered overweight.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Doswell_BMI
{
        //declaring important things
        static String weight;
        static String  height;
        static int multi;
        static int multi2;
        static String diagnosis;
        static int bmi;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            weight=  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your weight?");
            height= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height?");

            multi = 703;
            multi2 = 2;

            bmi = weight * multi / height * multi2;

            bmi = Integer.parseInt(diagnosis);


        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can not multiply `Strings` as they are so you need to convert to an Integer first

```
int w = Integer.valueOf (weight);
```

Comment: @martijn-p I am seriously in-decided about your suggested edit.  Where as, yes the code does use an `int` my feeling is that a float would be better.  As both `Integer` and `Float` extend `Number`, I was hoping to keep things ambiguous.  BTW thanks for the edit, and please let me know what you think.

Comment: True, but the reason I edited it is because some people (at least the ones I work with) like to use the generic Number class. Not that it's a massive change and it was impossible to understand or anything, but it could be seen as confusing. I do agree that a potential Float could be better, since we're talking about a weight here some people might want to provide more precise values (if you're borderline under/overweight), so I do agree that that may be something that could be a "nice to have"

Answer (score 0):

String cannot be multiply, try this:

```
bmi = Integer.valueOf(weight) * multi / Integer.valueOf(height) * multi2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using ints to calculate BMI. The equation for calculating BMI in pounds and inches is as follows:

If you’re 5’5” (65”) in height and 150lbs in weight, you would calculate your BMI as follows:

(150lbs / (65 inches²)) x 703 = 24.96.

150 / 65*65 = 0.03550295858 <- This is the reason you want to be using a data type such as double.

Answer (score 0):

> weight=  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your weight?");
>
> height= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height?");

These two statements return String values.
You cannot perform mathematical operations to string variables in JAVA.
Hence, you have to convert them to Integer using

either,
  `Integer.parseInt(weight)`
 this will convert the string into the primitive type `int`

or

`Integer.valueOf(weight)`
this will convert the string into an object of the wrapper class `Integer`

> bmi = weight * multi / height * multi2;

This multiplication is not very accurate as your requirement above is to first multiply the two sections separately and then divide

It is better if you write this as `bmi = (weight * multi) / (height * multi2)`

so the final statement will be `bmi = (weight.Integer.parseInt(weight) * multi) / (height.Integer.parseInt(height) * multi2)`